# IntelliJ 2018.1 issue with Spring Boot integration tests

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I upgraded my IntelliJ version from 2017.3 to 2018.1 and now I can't run integration tests from the IDE anymore.

The project is a Spring Boot application and build with gradle. The integration tests look basically like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = TestApplication.class,
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE
)
@Transactional
public class MyServiceIT {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It's still possible to run the test with gradle, but I can't run the isolated test from the IDE.

I get this error, because the instances cannot be autowired anymore:

```
[INFO] org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [MyServiceIT]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
[INFO] org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
[INFO] org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@309e345f, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@56a6d5a6, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@18ce0030, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@4445629, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@45b9a632, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@25d250c6, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener@4df50bcc, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@6b26e945, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@63a65a25, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@54c562f7, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@318ba8c8, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@6dbb137d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@3c9d0b9d]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name ...
```

I worked perfectly with version 2017.1. I think I have to change something in the IDEs configuration but I don't know what.

I'm using Windows 10, IntelliJ 2018.1, Java 1.8 and Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I made it running again. In the `Run/Debug Configurations` the `Working directory` was set to `$MODULE_DIR$`. In my project that did not resolve correctly. After setting the `Working directory` explicitly to the project root, running specific integration tests worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, in a situation like this, where tests work with Gradle, but not in IntelliJ, it's most of the time because the classes are out of sync. This should be possible to fix by rebuilding the project:

```
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

In particularly tenacious cases it might help to additionally clear the caches:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, rebuilding and invalidating the cache and restart didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to mark `src/main/test` as the "Test Sources Root".

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/testing.html#add-test-root

> Create a test root for your project﻿
>
> Follow these steps if you're building your project with the native
> IntelliJ IDEA builder:
>
> In the Project tool window (⌘ 1), right-click the directory in which you want to store your test code and select Mark Directory As |
> Test Sources Root.
>
> The tests folder should be marked with the the Tests root icon icon.

[image: Creating the test sources root]